"Failed to download packages: bind-chroot-32:9.11.36-11.el8_9.x86_64: Cannot download, all mirrors were already tried without success"
I've a jenkins pipeline it is failing since it is showing me this error
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to download packages: bind-chroot-32:9.11.36-11.el8_9.x86_64: Cannot download, all mirrors were already tried without success", "results": []}.
The thing is the jenkins is connected to Nexus when I checked Nexus it doesn't have this package in the Rhel-8 repository.
I might have found a solution that I have to upload that missing package in the S3 bucket and create an instance and mount that S3 bucket to that instance via s3fuse & reindex the repo data.
I tried this but it is failing to do the Job.
I might have found a solution that I have to upload that missing package in the S3 bucket and create an instance and mount that S3 bucket to that instance via s3fuse & reindex the repo data.
I tried this but it is failing to do the Job.
